# When a question is deleted by moderator, will the reputation received by answering be lost as well?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, up-votes

i recently answered a question and got upvoted for the answer. But the question was deleted later due to question being too generic. Then after a few minutes, i noticed that my reputation became the same as before when i got upvoted for it. Is this because the question was deleted? In such a case will the reputation earned be lost or was it maybe for some other reason that i overlooked??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if a question gets deleted means the reputation earned through its answers, edits, etc. will all be removed, with one exception:

If an answer scores 3 or more, and its question is deleted, any reputation earned more than 60 days before the deletion will be kept.